# Not getting user location

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I need to get the user's location.

I have included all three keys needed in info.plist

[image]

In the view Controller I have declared the variables:

```
       // Used to start getting the users location
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var currentLocation: CLLocation!
```

I have extended the view Controller with `CLLocationManagerDelegate`

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UISearchBarDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

And I have included this code in viewDidLoad:

```
  locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()


    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse) || (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways) {

                currentLocation = locationManager.location
                print(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
                print(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)

            }
```

The user is asked for permission, but the coordinates are not received.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to set the delegate and start monitoring.

Comment: @Don, would you mind telling me how do I start the monitoring?

Comment: Set the delegate, the desiredAccuracy and call `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`. If you do a search for those, I'm sure there are plenty of examples available.

Comment: @Don, done, thank you. I have included:   locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            print("estoy en location manager ",currentLocation as Any)
                    print(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
                    print(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)

                }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call startupdatinglocation() https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423750-startupdatinglocation in order to receive messages of CLLocationManagerDelegate

you can check https://fluffy.es/current-location/ for a complete tutorial